# How to create a constructor that accepts symbols, such as: *, +, (), etc

Tags: java, constructor, symbols

I am trying to pass certain types of characters, like the ones in the titles, through a constructor, and then assign an enum to it.

I have an enum class that has three values: NUMBER, STRING, and SYMBOL.

I have three constructors:

```
(float x) {}
(String str){}
(Symbol value) {}
```

When a float is passed, I assign a variable 'type' to Type.STRING. The same goes for strings, but with Type.STRING.

How can I do this for various symbols (such as those in the title)? When I create an instance of Entry and try to pass, say, a plus character (+), I get the message, 'Syntax error on token "+", delete this token'.

```
public class Entry{
    private Type type;

    public Entry(Type value) {
        this.type = Type.SYMBOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your constructor takes instances of your enum, + is not one of those. What did you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java `+` is an [operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). It can only be used as part of an expression, not by itself.

You can however pass a String that contains `+` like this: `"+"` or use an enum that represents different operators:

```
enum Operator {
    PLUS, MINUS;
}
```

Then your constructor can accept such an enum:

```
public Entry(Operator op) {
}
```

Another option is to create an "addition" function that can add two elements together, and pass that function to the constructor. However, that's slightly trickier and requires knowing what type of thing you're adding:

```
BiFunction<MyObject, MyObject, MyObject> addition =  (a,b) -> {
    //implement a+b here;
    //return result;
}
```

Then the constructor could be something like this:

```
public Entry(BiFunction<MyObject, MyObject, MyObject> func) {
}
```